# How install Rsymphony in Mac OS X 10.14

Tags: r, macos, installation

I have seen a lot of solutions to this problem before, but they can't solve it.

```
> install.packages("Rsymphony")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rsymphony’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) y
installing the source package ‘Rsymphony’

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rsymphony_0.1-28.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8631 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 8631 bytes

* installing *source* package ‘Rsymphony’ ...
** 成功将‘Rsymphony’程序包解包并MD5和检查
Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.
See <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rsymphony’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rsymphony’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rsymphony’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/b0/n64bqfyn5y9dr3t427tljzv40000gn/T/RtmptYuOGn/downloaded_packages’
```

Before

```
brew install symphony
```

And Modify file `R_symphony.cc & configure`.

But there is still no change in this issue.

I know `“SystemRequirements:    SYMPHONY libraries and headers”`，But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: As the Optimization Task View says: "Package lsymphony in Bioconductor provides a similar interface to SYMPHONY that is easier to install."

Comment: @HansW. I tried to use ```BiocManager::install("Rsymphony")```. Is this the way you said? I am sorry that I first heard about Bioconductor. Can you please tell me in detail how should I use it?Thank you very much！

Comment: Sorry, the name of this package on Bioconductor is "lpsymphony", so the right call is `BiocManager::install("lpsymphony")`. (This has to be corrected on the task view, too.)

Comment: @HansW.Thank you, I understand. Under Mac OS ```Rsymphony``` is called ```lpsymphony```.Really Thanks!

Comment: That is wrong. `lpsymphony` is a package that runs on Linux, macOS, or Windows. It is simply an alternative for wrapping the COIN-OR program SYMPHONY. It is easier to install because: "The main difference between this package and Rsymphony is that it includes the solver source code (SYMPHONY version 5.6), while Rsymphony expects to find header and library files on the users' system. "

Comment: @HansW. That's it, thank you, I understand.